# Backbone Marionette. Rendering a view does not fire onRender?

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

I have an event firing which executes 'this.render' in an ItemView. This line of code is definitely run.

However neither the onBeforeRender nor the onRender events are fired.

They are fired when the View is shown into a region.

Is this expected behaviour?

Thanks

--Justin Wyllie

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. Minor bug. this.render(). Duh!